# How to manage dependencies when converting a directory into npm package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

A project write in react, with a directory maybe `ui-components`.

And now I'm trying convert this directory into a npm package.

The easy part is that `package.json` tells where to find components to import, which is write as `"main": "./src/index.js"`.

It works perfect, and it can import things from outside `node_modules` directory since nothing is installed in `ui-components/node_modules`.

But as a package, I'm trying add `@storybook/react` and maybe other dependencies, some of them are consistent but has different version.

Is there a way I can easily use the outside `node_modules` as I do now, or is there a way to simply synchronize the version in `ui-components/package.json` with the outside `package.json`?

> I'm not going to install the inside `ui-components`, but I want to code them together and release the inside one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies)

"In some cases, you want to express the compatibility of your package with a host tool or library, while not necessarily doing a require of this host. This is usually referred to as a plugin. Notably, your module may be exposing a specific interface, expected and specified by the host documentation."

```
{
  "name": "tea-latte",
  "version": "1.3.5",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "tea": "2.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'm looking for a package manage tool like [`lerna`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna) or [`@microsoft/rush`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/rush).

And in my case, it's a bit different and I may write some build script to deal with these package manage stuff.

Comment: In yarn, you can set a resolutions field in package.json which is used to overwrite the package's version in dependencies.